# A thread-safe initialization guard

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have written a type with the following public API:

```
public sealed class InitializationGuard
{
    public bool IsUninitialized
    {
        get;
    }

    public bool IsInitializing
    {
        get;
    }

    public bool IsInitialized
    {
        get;
    }

    public InitializationTransaction BeginInitialization();

    public bool TryBeginInitialization(out InitializationTransaction initializationTransaction);

    public void EnsureInitialized();
}
```

The intention is to use it in services that require initialization, possibly asynchronous with multiple threads attempting to initialize them at once. Something like this:

```
public sealed class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly InitializationGuard initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();

    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        using (var transaction = this.initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            await SomeInitLogic();

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingThatRequiresInitialization()
    {
        this.initializationGuard.EnsureInitialized();

        await SomeOtherLogic();
    }
}
```

The idea is to save having to write this kind of guard logic in every service.

My questions are:

1. is this a valid approach?
2. am I kidding myself that this is truly thread-safe?
3. is there perhaps a better approach to the implementation? I'm not particularly happy with the pattern that emerges when using `TryBeginInitialization()`, but am not really sure of any viable alternative

Here is the full code (apart from `DisposableBase`, which just provides thread-safety when disposing):

### InitializationGuard

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

[DebuggerDisplay("Initialized: {IsInitialized}")]
public sealed class InitializationGuard
{
    private const int Uninitialized = 0;
    private const int Initializing = 1;
    private const int Initialized = 2;
    private int initializationState;

    public bool IsUninitialized
    {
        get { return this.IsInInitializationState(Uninitialized); }
    }

    public bool IsInitializing
    {
        get { return this.IsInInitializationState(Initializing); }
    }

    public bool IsInitialized
    {
        get { return this.IsInInitializationState(Initialized); }
    }

    public InitializationTransaction BeginInitialization()
    {
        InitializationTransaction initializationTransaction;

        if (!this.TryBeginInitialization(out initializationTransaction))
        {
            throw new InitializationException("Initialization already instigated.");
        }

        return initializationTransaction;
    }

    public bool TryBeginInitialization(out InitializationTransaction initializationTransaction)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.initializationState, Initializing, Uninitialized) != Uninitialized)
        {
            initializationTransaction = null;
            return false;
        }

        initializationTransaction = new InitializationTransaction(this);
        return true;
    }

    public void EnsureInitialized()
    {
        if (!this.IsInitialized)
        {
            throw new InitializationException("Not yet initialized.");
        }
    }

    internal void InitializationTransactionComplete(InitializationTransaction initializationTransaction)
    {
        var newState = initializationTransaction.IsCommitted ? Initialized : Uninitialized;
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.initializationState, newState);
    }

    private bool IsInInitializationState(int initializationState)
    {
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.initializationState, initializationState, initializationState) == initializationState;
    }
}
```

### InitializationTransaction

```
public sealed class InitializationTransaction : DisposableBase
{
    private readonly InitializationGuard owner;
    private volatile bool isCommitted;

    internal InitializationTransaction(InitializationGuard owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public bool IsCommitted
    {
        get { return this.isCommitted; }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        this.isCommitted = true;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        if (disposing)
        {
            this.owner.InitializationTransactionComplete(this);
        }
    }
}
```

### InitializationException

```
using System;

public sealed class InitializationException : Exception
{
    public InitializationException()
    {
    }

    public InitializationException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public InitializationException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

### InitializationGuardFixture

```
using Xunit;

public sealed class InitializationGuardFixture
{
    [Fact]
    public void an_in_flight_initialization_has_a_state_of_initializing()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();

        using (initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            Assert.True(initializationGuard.IsInitializing);
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void an_uncommitted_initialization_reverts_the_state_to_uninitialized()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();
        initializationGuard
            .BeginInitialization()
            .Dispose();

        Assert.True(initializationGuard.IsUninitialized);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void a_committed_initialization_changes_the_state_to_initialized()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();

        using (var initializationTransaction = initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            initializationTransaction.Commit();
        }

        Assert.True(initializationGuard.IsInitialized);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void cannot_begin_initialization_if_already_initializing()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();

        using (initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            var ex = Assert.Throws<InitializationException>(() => initializationGuard.BeginInitialization());
            Assert.Equal("Initialization already instigated.", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void cannot_begin_initialization_if_already_initialized()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();

        using (var initializationTransaction = initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            initializationTransaction.Commit();
        }

        var ex = Assert.Throws<InitializationException>(() => initializationGuard.BeginInitialization());
        Assert.Equal("Initialization already instigated.", ex.Message);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void trying_to_initialize_returns_true_if_initialization_not_yet_instigated()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();
        InitializationTransaction initializationTransaction;

        Assert.True(initializationGuard.TryBeginInitialization(out initializationTransaction));
        Assert.NotNull(initializationTransaction);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void trying_to_initialize_returns_false_if_already_initializing()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();

        using (initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            InitializationTransaction initializationTransaction;
            Assert.False(initializationGuard.TryBeginInitialization(out initializationTransaction));
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void trying_to_initialize_returns_false_if_already_initialized()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();
        InitializationTransaction initializationTransaction;

        using (initializationTransaction = initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            initializationTransaction.Commit();
        }

        Assert.False(initializationGuard.TryBeginInitialization(out initializationTransaction));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ensure_initialized_succeeds_if_initialized()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();

        using (var initializationTransaction = initializationGuard.BeginInitialization())
        {
            initializationTransaction.Commit();
        }

        initializationGuard.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ensure_initialized_fails_if_not_yet_initialized()
    {
        var initializationGuard = new InitializationGuard();
        var ex = Assert.Throws<InitializationException>(() => initializationGuard.EnsureInitialized());
        Assert.Equal("Not yet initialized.", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to create an inner implementing class then `Lazy<>` create it? `Lazy<>` is thread safe so you don't have to manually manage the initialization process, you just simply use it.

Comment: @Jeff: well, `Lazy<T>` does not have asynchronous semantics. I could use [AsyncLazy<T>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/10116210.aspx) but I'm not convinced it has the same behavior as my solution. e.g. throwing exceptions if already initialized and a transient "initializing" state.

Answer (score 2):

```
private const int Uninitialized = 0;
private const int Initializing = 1;
private const int Initialized = 2;
```

These constants really smell like they want to be an `enum`.

```
public bool IsUninitialized
{
    get { return this.IsInInitializationState(Uninitialized); }
}

public bool IsInitializing
{
    get { return this.IsInInitializationState(Initializing); }
}

public bool IsInitialized
{
    get { return this.IsInInitializationState(Initialized); }
}
```

With an `enum InitializationState` you wouldn't need these three getters, and could simply make `IsInInitializationState` public, taking an `InitializationState` parameter instead of an `int`, and `this.initializationState` would be an `InitializationState` instead of an `int`, too. The naming already seems to be asking for that.

Comment: Fair points, Mat. Actually, I started with an enum but switched to ints because the casting looked messy (have to cast to `int` to use `Interlocked`). Maybe I'll change it back and see if I think it's cleaner.